# maven + oracle - unable to set jdbc connector from POM

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jdbc

I'm building a maven project with Oracle connection, but I'm having always some answer after 'mvn package' command:

```
Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0 in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository
```

I've allready installed locally my jdbc jar file with this command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={/path_to_my_jar/ojdbc6.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and my pom is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.albert</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringHibernate</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>SpringHibernate</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  

<!-- JBoss repository for Hibernate -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You will never find oracle drivers in Maven Central. You need to download them manually and do it via `mvn install:install-file` or take a look at oracle they have in the mean time an Maven repository which needs credentials.

Comment: if yu have already locally installed yur jar look ojdbc6.jar is installed in your Maven local repository.

Comment: @khmarbaise look his post he have allready installed locally jdbc jar file with the command:

Comment: looking at mvn install command, I see the .m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0  directory does not have the jar but console said it has

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

`-U` means force update of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with these steps:

- after my 'mvn install:install-file...' command above the jar seems to be NOT in '.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0' directory, so I manually copy in there calling it 'ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar'
- mvn package now goes well

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use this dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>cn.guoyukun.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>oracle-ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.2.0.3.0</version></dependency>
```

Comment: why change repo, he has the jar in his file .M2. The pb is not the repo ..?

Comment: because there is NO public Maven repository provides Oracle JDBC driver.

Comment: We can use the dependency before or run this command first: mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle 
-DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar and then the reference to the pom.xml